# How to compare two lists and print the difference in one list

Tags: python, list, set, comparison

I'm trying to extract usernames from a config file into a list and compare the usernames against another secure list of usernames.
The config file looks like this this:

```
username Hilton privilege 15 password 0 $xxxxxxxxxxxxx
username gooduser password 0 $xxxxxxxxxxxxx
username jason secret 5 $xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The problem with the output is not a single list! (each user is in a list)

```
['Hilton']
['gooduser']
['jason']
```

I am reading the file into one single list.
Then located the 'username' position and used enumerate to find the position

```
the_list = []

with open('config_file.txt', "r") as f:
    the_list = f.read().split()        
    print(the_list)
    find_keyword = 'username'

    secure_users = ['jason','test','admin']

for i,x in enumerate(the_list):   # search in the list
  if x=='username':               # for this keyword 'username'
     pos = i + 1                  # position of every username 

     print(the_list[pos].split())          # print all users.

#Compare secure_users[] vs the_list[] here
```

the expected output is a list like >> ['Hilton','gooduser','jason']

So that I can compare it against the secure_users list

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly

Comment: Is the username always at the second position in your config file? Right after the keyword `username`?

Comment: Yes always Right after the keyword username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some modification to your code,

```
the_list = []

with open('config_file.txt', "r") as f:
    the_list = f.read().split()        
    print(the_list)
find_keyword = 'username'

secure_users = ['jason','test','admin']

users_list = []
for i,x in enumerate(the_list):   # search in the list
    if x=='username':               # for this keyword 'username'
        pos = i + 1                  # position of every username 

        users_list.append(the_list[pos].split()[0])          # print all users
print(users_list)
```

---

**Output:**

```
['username', 'Hilton', 'privilege', '15', 'password', '0', '$xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'username', 'gooduser', 'password', '0', '$xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'username', 'jason', 'secret', '5', '$xxxxxxxxxxxxx']
['Hilton', 'gooduser', 'jason']
```

**Another solution:(Best way)**

```
with open('config_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().split()
    user_names = [data[i+1] for i,line in enumerate(data) if 'username' in line ]
```

---

**Output:**

```
['Hilton', 'gooduser', 'jason']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
usernames = []
secure_users = ['jason','test','admin']
with open('config_file.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        usernames.append(line.split()[1])

print([user for user in secure_users if user in usernames])
```

Comment: That's not the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

find_keyword = 'username'
the_list = []
with open('config_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r"\b{}\b \b(.*?)\b ".format(find_keyword), line.strip())    #Search for key and word after that. 
        if m:
            the_list.append(m.group(1))

print(the_list)# ->['Hilton', 'gooduser', 'jason']
```

Answer (score 0):

add a list named diff in your code like :

```
diff = []
```

then Just add below 2 lines after your code line print(the_list[pos].split()):

```
if the_list[pos] not in secure_users:
        diff.append(the_list[pos])
```

then print diff to see the single list:

```
print(diff)
```